# Jest / React Testing Library: Is it Possible to Spy on and Wait GraphQL Queries as with Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, cypress, apollo-client, react-testing-library

Most of my testing experience is with Cypress. I'm attempting to test some React components with React Testing Library (henceforth referred to as  "RTL"). I'm wondering if I can apply some of the techniques I use with Cypress.

I have a section of my (web) app which displays a table of search results from a DB. The search API is implemented in GraphQL. We use Apollo on the frontend. Searches can be filtered vis-a-vis a `<FilterCheckbox/>` component. It includes four checkboxes and a "Clear All" button. The checkbox state is stored in the Apollo cache.

I'm writing a spec for this component. I wish to test that the first two checkboxes are selected by default and that clicking "Clear Filters" deselects them all. I have the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import FilterCheckboxes from './FilterCheckboxes'
import { render, fireEvent } from 'Utils/test-utils'

import {
  getByText,
  getByTestId
} from '@testing-library/dom'

const props = {
  options: [
    { label: 'new', value: 'FRESH' },
    { label: 'active', value: 'ACTIVE' },
    { label: 'closed', value: 'CLOSED' },
    { label: 'removed', value: 'ARCHIVED' },
  ],
  statusArray: [
    'FRESH',
    'ACTIVE',
  ],
  cacheKey: 'status',
}

describe('FilterCheckboxes component', () => {
  const { container } = render(<FilterCheckboxes {...props} />)

  const checkNew = getByTestId(container,'checkbox_new')
    .querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')

  const checkActive = getByTestId(container, 'checkbox_active')
    .querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')

  const checkClosed = getByTestId(container,'checkbox_closed' )
    .querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')

  const checkRemoved = getByTestId(container, 'checkbox_removed')
    .querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')

  const clearButton = getByText(container, 'clear status filters')


  it('should render the checkboxes with the correct default state', () => {
    expect(checkNew).toHaveProperty('checked', true)
    expect(checkActive).toHaveProperty('checked', true)
    expect(checkClosed).toHaveProperty('checked', false)
    expect(checkRemoved).toHaveProperty('checked', false)
  })

  it('Should clear all checkboxes when clear filters is clicked', () => {
    fireEvent.click(clearButton)
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(checkNew).toHaveProperty('checked', false)
      expect(checkActive).toHaveProperty('checked', false)
      expect(checkClosed).toHaveProperty('checked', false)
      expect(checkRemoved).toHaveProperty('checked', false)
    }, 500)
  })
})
```

The tests pass, but the second one only passes if I do this arbitrary delay of 500ms. Without it, the checkboxes are still in the default state when the `expect()` calls fire.

If this were a Cypress test and the onClick called a REST API, I would do something like this:

```
cy.server()
cy.route('POST', '/foo/bar/v2', '@someAliasedFixture').as('fooBar')

cy.get('.my-button')
.click()
.then(() => {
    cy.wait('@fooBar')
    // continue test here as we know that the call completed
})
```

Is it possible to do something like this with Jest / RTL / GraphQL / Apollo?

**Update:**
Took another look this morning. It appears that `waitFor()` is the function intended to be used in async scenarios. However, if I do

```
it('should deselect checkboxes when Clear Filters is clicked', async () => {
  fireEvent.click(clearButton)
  waitFor(expect(checkNew).toHaveProperty('checked', false))
})
```

It just fails because the checkbox is still selected. Surely there is a way to test this with RTL?

Based on the examples I've looked at, the orthodox approach seems to be to pass the click handler function as a prop and `expect()` it `.toHaveBeenCalled()` called.

Is that correct? This seems wrong to me. My component isn't what makes onClick handlers fire in response to click events. React.js makes that happen. Checking that `foo()` gets called when clicking on `<MyComponent onClick={foo}/>` isn't testing that *my* code works. It's testing that React.js works.

**SOLVED!**
Thanks to @flo:

```
  it('should render the checkboxes with the correct default state', () => {
    expect(checkNew).toBeChecked()
    expect(checkActive).toBeChecked()
    expect(checkClosed).not.toBeChecked()
    expect(checkRemoved).not.toBeChecked()
  })

  it('should deselect checkboxes when Clear Filters is clicked', async () => {
    fireEvent.click(clearButton)
    waitFor(() => {
      expect(checkNew).not.toBeChecked()
      expect(checkActive).not.toBeChecked()
      expect(checkClosed).not.toBeChecked()
      expect(checkRemoved).not.toBeChecked()
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, you should test as a real user would, so you should definitely test that the checkbox is in the correct state instead of testing that the click handler was called. This is what promotes react-testing-library.

Are you sure about this ?

```
expect(checkNew).toHaveProperty('checked', false);
```

I never used this, but reading the docs I'm not sure if this would do the job (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavepropertykeypath-value). In fact I don't see how it could work.

Have you consider using https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom, and in particular https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobechecked ?

Comment: YASSSSSS! That worked! Thank you so much! Now I can enjoy my Sunday. You're the dude, man!

Comment: Great :). Happy Sunday !